# How do I install "user-theme" extension for Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, themes, extension, users

Is there any way (preferably simple) to install the user-theme extension for Gnome 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download this package! [here](http://db.tt/hk3q6ak)! You will need Common package too!

Comment: FYI, your debs are giving me a warning about the email address you used ("maintainer address malformed"). It's showing your computer name. You might want to fix that.